# Using java driver create sequence on Greenplum/Postgresql database doesn't work

Tags: postgresql, greenplum

I use Greenplum/PostgreSQL for database.

I plan to create sequence via jdbc,but doesn't work.

```
val conn=getConnection();
val st=conn.createState();
st.execute("CREATE SEQUENCE SEQ_4_MT_QUERY  INCREMENT BY 1  MINVALUE 0  MAXVALUE 99999999  START 0   CACHE 3  cycle");
conn.close();
```

No errors occur, but the sequence isn't created.

Any one have this experience? Thanks.

Greenplum is the latest edition 
Jdbc driver version is: PostgreSQL-9.4.1212

Comment: `conn.commit();` maybe?

Comment: Are you using Greenplum or Postgres?

Comment: Oh,use conn.commit(),that works,create successfully! Thanks  @a_horse_with_no_name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your connection is not in auto-commit mode, you must commit your DDL statement (at least in Postgres - I assume this is the same in Greenplum).

So you need to add:

```
conn.commit();
```

after the `execute()` call.

Answer (score 0):

I need commit to database.

The create sql takes effect until calls conn.commit(),this depends on the database  connection pool settings,but I use the pool sets this commit auto.Now I think this setting is not work.

Thanks [a_horse_with_no_name](https://stackoverflow.com/users/330315/a-horse-with-no-name)'s suggestion